# Do the effects of rings stack?

Tags: pixel-dungeon

For example, if I equip two rings of mending, do their effects on my health regeneration stack?

I'm guessing it will be easiest to check this with two rings of detection, but I haven't had the chance to find two of these in the same game yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It does stack. Member of wiki discovered. Search in-page for word stack and you will see: http://pixeldungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:3013

> Rings appear to stack (besides ring of haggler)...
>
> With two rings of mending + 2, natural regeneration is more than
>   doubled.  Without the two rings, the hp regen appears to be +1 per 10
>   ticks (wait actions).  With 1 ring the hp regen is +1/7 ish, and with 2
>   rings, the hp regen is a little faster than +1/5.  The rings appear to
>   have no effect when starving.